# Which software can view .torrent metainfo?

Tags: windows, macos, software-rec

Looking for software which can show the content of `.torrent` including all files, folders and size of files. Preferable under windows, but OS X also should be fine.

Update:

The subject is **not a torrent client**, but just lightweight software not related to networking, just parsing bencoded data inside of torrent file and show me. Bencode editor is one example of such software. However, it doesn't show the file sizes.

Comment: Any torrent client would do the trick

Comment: personally I use http://www.utorrent.com/ uTorrent - it's very lightweight but does everything you need.

Comment: Please see my update. I'm not looking for torrent client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any torrent client, but don't press "download" button.

To be sure you can also [mis]cofigure proxy server setting to non-existing one (like http://127.0.0.1:1/) to ensure it can't connect anywhere.

Comment: I know this way. But as you can see it's not perfectly comfortable way and not designed to serve as solely viewer. I was hoping to find something like GTorrentViewer under Windows or OS X.

Comment: May be you can build GTorrentViewer on Windows and OS X?

Comment: Nop, I'm not into such magic just to view metadata.